# pjax event listeners not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, github, google-chrome-extension, pjax

I am writing an [chrome extension](https://github.com/mesuutt/github-annotator) related with Github. I want to trigger a function when user click to public activity tab on Github user profile page.I am adding pjax success event listener in extension but not triggering anytime.

I am adding jquery.pjax.js to manifest.json and adding below code in contentscript.js but function not calling when pjax request succeed:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

How can I run function when pjax succeed in chrome extension?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the extension JavaScript is sandboxed from webpage javascript (as well as events), so you can't listen on that event ;/